# Laptop turns off on its own in 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, power-management

I recently upgraded to 13.10 from 12.10. It's now showing the battery info wrong and it keeps turning off even with 60% of power remaining, and without warning. When I resboot the PC, it works fine for 30 minutes or so and then the same thing over again.

I didn't had this problem with 12.10. Also, I have installed TLP, but that's not helping either.

The hardware:

- PC: HP 2000-2116tu
- CPU: Intel i5 (3rd generation)
- Graphics: Intel HD4000

Comment: Please add more information about your hardware by [edit]ing your question. PC model? CPU? Graphics card?

Comment: Notice that it might be a problem with the battery (it might be failing). Do you dual-boot with Windows? If so, do you have the same problem while running Windows? Under the battery indicator (top right little battery icon), I think there's an option to see some battery statistics.

Comment: ya ,  I use  to dual boot and it gives about 2.5 hrs of backup in windows.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

make sure you haven't changed anything in power settings.

Comment: your "when power is critically low" shows blank but mine have power off and hibernate. Rest of the settings are same .